# Save userId on model Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question related with how to save the user information with firebase. I extended the user authentication and created a new node on the json tree with users, each user has his own id generated by firebase and the user info is inside that key/id. The thing is, each time I do this:

```
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    if (number.equals(String.valueOf(user.getPhone()))) {
                        Log.d("here", "i entered");
                        key = snapshot.getKey();
                        userFriend = user;
                    }


                }
```

I map the user info inside that key inside my user model that I have in my code, but in my project next steps I need to have the key for the specific user too. And here I am just mapping the user info without the key. Is there a way I can add a string id inside my model and  automatically add the key to that id field?

**userModel**

```
package com.esmad.pdm.friendlymanager.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class User {

    private String id;
    private String username;
    private int age = -1;
    private String phone;
    private int gamesPlayed = 0;
    private ArrayList<User> FriendList = new ArrayList<User>();

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    // GETTERS & SETTERS
    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }

    public User(String id, String username, int age, String phone, int gamesPlayed, ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.username = username;
        this.age = age;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed;
        this.FriendList = users;
    }



    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }

    public String getPhone() { return phone; }
    public void setPhone(String phone) { this.phone = phone; }

    public int getGamesPlayed() { return gamesPlayed; }
    public void setGamesPlayed(int gamesPlayed) { this.gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed; }

    public ArrayList<User> getUsers() { return FriendList; }
    public void setUsers(ArrayList<User> users) { this.FriendList = users; }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to get the key of the snapshot automatically injected when you call `snapshot.getValue(User.class)`.

But you can easily add an extra call that adds the key to the `User` object. You'll first need to add a getter and setter for `id` to your `User` class:

```
@Exclude
public String getId() { return id; }
@Exclude
public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }
```

As you probably already noticed I annotated these with `@Exclude`. This tells the database client to ignore the properties when reading from/writing to the database. Without the annotation, you'd also get an `id` property in each User's node in the database.

Now you can simply set and get the key when you're reading the property values:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
        user.setId(snapshot.getKey());
        System.out.println(user.getId());
    }
}
```

In the above snippet `snapshot.getValue(User.class)` gets a user object with all the regular properties, and then `user.setId(snapshot.getKey())` adds the key to that object.

When writing back to the database you could also use `user.getId()` to determine where to write:

```
ref.child(user.getId()).setValue(user);
```