# Save pushed id in Firebase Model

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got 2 firebase questions here :

A/ Is it a good practice to programmatically **copy the ID to the local model** (excluded from the database), when parsing a value ?

- Frank, from Firebase, suggests that solution: [Save userId on model Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705871/save-userid-on-model-firebase/43707994#43707994)

B/ Another solution would be to :

- Generate a new key
- Use that key and **duplicate it to the model**
- Save the model (and the key) to database

```
val newPostRef = ref.child("posts").push()
val key = newPostRef.key
newPostRef.setValue(Post(key, "title", "content"))
```

Like this, the post id will be hold by the database model and parsed automatically with **getValue(Post::class)**.

I can feel that is not a good solution, but please tell me why :)

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions guarantee data consistency, but solution A is better than solution B when it comes to database size.

By using solution B, your database structure would look like this:

```
"posts":{
    "nTY5U5NJJbPTJaPksPRNqau15H53" : {
      "message" : "Hello World",
      "sender" : "Rosário Pereira Fernandes",
      "key" : "nTY5U5NJJbPTJaPksPRNqau15H53"
    }
}
```

This should use around **180 bytes** of disk space. Notice that this key is repeated twice on your node. Why not remove it to save space?

Using solution B, you'd have a smaller database:

```
"posts":{
    "nTY5U5NJJbPTJaPksPRNqau15H53" : {
      "message" : "Hello World",
      "sender" : "Rosário Pereira Fernandes"
    }
}
```

This would use around **135 bytes**. That's **45 bytes** less than solution B. Now imagine if you had 1000 posts on your database. You'd be using **45000 bytes** more on solution B. This is enough space to store around 300 more posts, but it is being taken by the extra key attribute.

Don't forget that the [Firebase Database has some price limitations](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) for GB stored and GB downloaded. By using solution B you would reach this limit faster than by using solution A.