# How can I read the unique key provided by firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

How can I read the unique key created by `push()` firebase database and save it to same database object?

```
     buttonSave.setOnClickListener(){
     val recKey = "????" 

     var record = Record(recKey, textDescription.text, textAddress.text)

         mDatabase.setValue(record) 

         finish()
       }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48184670/5861618) and the posts linked there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first create the `push()` then get it's `key`. Then use the `key` when writing to the Database:

```
 buttonSave.setOnClickListener(){
 val recKey = mDatabase.push().key 

 var record = Record(recKey, textDescription.text, textAddress.text)

     mDatabase.child(recKey).setValue(record) 

     finish()
   }
}
```

Comment: this creates additional nodes on my database

Comment: Then use `mDatabase.setValue(record)`  instead