# Firebase Database: Where to store they upload key?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I just can't figure out where to store the key for the database node so I can later use it to find and delete an entry.
Right now I store that key inside my `Upload` object, but I saw someone mentioning that this is bad practice. I can't find an explanation online.

Right now I do my uploads like this:

```
mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                        mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                    }
                })
```

And then when I query my database, I store the key inside the same Upload object:

```
mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            mUploads.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());

                mUploads.add(upload);
            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

This is my upload class. They key field is not appearing in the database (and I don't want it to):

```
public class Upload {
private String mName;
private String mImageUrl;
private String mKey;

public Upload() {
    // Needed for Firebase reflection
}

public Upload(String name, String imageUrl) {
    if (name.trim().equals("")) {
        name = "No Name";
    }

    mName = name;
    mImageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    mName = name;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return mImageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    mImageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getKey() {
    return mKey;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    mKey = key;
}
}
```

This works, it's just that I found very very little examples that do the same.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: When does a user delete an entry? Have you written the code to delete?

Comment: Yes I have added a Floating Context Menu to the RecyclerView items and in the same activity as I read the data, I have a callback for that delete button. There I get send the object/position of the clicked item

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood at first... The solution you're using is perfectly fine and it was actually recommended by a Firebase Engineer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705871/save-userid-on-model-firebase/43707994#43707994). (You might want to also have a look at this [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48186783/5861618))

Comment: Yessss, amazing, thank you. This is exactly what I wanted to see!

Answer (score 0):

i just store my key in a putExtra, but you can store it in sharedPreferences as well, i put my key in putextras because i will need it in another Activity, for example.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserEdit.class);
 intent.putExtra("uid",mDatabase.getKey());
```

and then i can get that in my UserEdit.class as below

```
 Intent iin= getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

        if(b!=null)
        {

            final String uid =(String) b.get("uid");
}
```

also, you can store it in a sharedPrefs value as below

**onCreate**

```
SharedPreferences sharedprefs =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

and then just store the value

```
 sharedprefs.edit().putString("key", mDatabaseRef.push().getKey()).apply();
```

and then retrieve it wherever you want like this

```
sharedprefs.getString("key","error");
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to know how to store it temporarily in relation to my upload object so I can identify it later. I don't mean persisting it long term. There must be a misunderstanding.